# Web Authentication API strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, authentication, browser, webapi, webauthn

I want to build application where users can login using mobile fingerprint sensor, pin or face id. I found that [Web Authentication API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API) provides me with feature like this, But it behaves strangely when I try to use already created demo from internet (for example [Webauthn.io](https://webauthn.io/)). I have iPhone and have latest google chrome and safari browsers inside. When I try this demos using chrome, it says that Web Authentication API is not supported, and when I try safari,  it says:

> "'webauthn.io' would like to enroll a security key. Insert your
> security key or bring the key near the top of your iPhone. Then,
> activate the key"

so what is happening? what should i do? does this mean that there's no point using Web Authentication API because it lacks browser support?

Answer (score 0):

Support for Face/Touch ID in WebAuthn on iOS won't be available until iOS 14 which is currently in the private beta. I'd suggest getting a developer account (if you haven't already) and test it out.

Note that as of the current beta version there are some restrictions that mean current demo sites may not work. Apple currently require the WebAuthn call to be directly initiated by a user interaction (e.g. a button press). This can cause issues where the application does a fetch call between the user interaction and the WebAuthn call as it loses the context. Hopefully that issue will be dealt with in due course.

Link to above issue: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213595